# Array of struct inside of a struct

Tags: c, struct

why can't i do this:

```
 typedef struct _word{
      struct _word ws[ 28 ];
 }Word;
```

With the code above i'm get the error: field 'ws' has incomplete type.

Why can i do just this:

```
 typedef struct _word{
      struct _word *wr[ 28 ];
 }Word;
```

I want static memory.

Comment: What would be the size of such a `Word` object? (+1 however, not so clear/useful diagnostic error)

Comment: The first version is nonsense anyway. What is it supposed to do ? It's a recursive definition.

Comment: Infinite regression: Word would have 28 _words. Each of those would have 28 _words. And each of those would have 28 _words.....ad infintum.

Answer (score 3):

Because if your structure is not completely defined, you can't calculate the size of the object to be allocated. As others mentioned, it'll be an infinite regression trying to deduce the size of the object.

But you can always calculate the size of a pointer. Hence the 2nd version works.